# Ubuntu not detecting my Wifi adapter?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, ethernet

I'm new to Ubuntu and the Linux operating systems, and I've recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I tried connecting to the internet and saw that Ubuntu didn't recognise my WiFi adapter. After some searching on Google, I found that it's most likely an issue with my network drivers, and all of the solutions I found were to connect my PC via ethernet to the internet, get the drivers I need and then finish.

Unfortunatly that's not an option for me, since my PC and my modem are far apart, so I'm not able to connect an ethernet cable between them.
And I know that the adapter works, it works just fine on Windows 10, so my only thoughts is that it's the drivers.

So my question is, is there somewhere where I can download these drivers on Windows, put them on a USB, boot up Ubuntu and install them that way?
And if not, what are any other solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alright, I found the drivers for my adapter, but I don't know how to install it, I found (The picture I added to the main post) in the files, don't know if it's any help

Comment: What exact Wi-Fi adapter model do you have?